# Can we make an algorithm for Schur Decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, unitary-matrices

> **Schur's Theorem**
>   If $A$ is any $n \times n$ complex matrix, there exist a unitary matrix $U$ such that
>   $$U^*AU=T$$
>   is upper triangular. Moreover, the entries on the main diagonal of $T$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

I've read the proof in W. Keith Nicholson's book *Linear Algebra with Applications* and I don't know how to make an algorithm from it since the proof is by induction. So, is there any way to find the unitary matrix $U$ satisfying the Schur's Theorem?

Comment: See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Computation)

Comment: I still can't find the use of the QR decomposition. Can you explain it briefly?

Comment: It's the QR algorithm, not the QR decomposition. Start with $A_0 = A$; given $A_k$, write the QR decomposition $A_k = Q_k R_k$ and take $A_{k+1} = R_k Q_k$.  The sequence $A_k$ converges to $T$ (under appropriate conditions).  Note that $A_k = Q_k A_{k+1} Q_k^*$, so $U = \lim_{k \to \infty} Q_0 Q_1 \ldots Q_k$.

Comment: Hmm..so it's not that simple. But thank you for the explanation.

Comment: In Wikipedia the QR algorithm is stated only for real matrices. Where can I find a programmable algorithm for Schur decomposition for the general case?